# Ajax asynchronous in ruby helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, asynchronous

I'd like to know how to run an asynchronous ajax request through a ruby on rails helper.
To be more specific, I need to call `remote_function`:

```
remote_function  :url => { :action => "draw_graph" }, :after => "do_something_after_ajax_is_done()" }
```

But `do_something_after_ajax_is_done()` is executing while ajax request is running and it mess up my plans.

I thought of using `:async => false or :asynchronous => false` option but it does not seem to work. Could you help me on the syntax or tell me what is wrong with my  way of doing it.

Is `remote_function` even taking option for asynchronous option?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want :complete

```
  remote_function  :url => { :action => "draw_graph" }, :complete => "do_something_after_ajax_is_done();"
```

this will run when the Ajax request has returned. If you only want to run if it's successful, use :success

```
  remote_function  :url => { :action => "draw_graph" }, :success => "do_something_after_ajax_is_done();"
```

Comment: you Matt, are my god. I spent 2days on this and end up with a very dirty "setTimeout". By the way do you know where i can find a complete guide for RoR helpers, the official API s*cks (it does not mention the :complete option for exemple)

Comment: apparently :asynchronous => false just isn't an option? weird.